# socket io/ count the number of radio button "ok"

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to count the number of how many users radio buttom of "btnok",
I am glad if you help.

```
enter code here<div class="sample clearfix">
    <input type="radio" name="s2" id="off" value="0" checked="checked">
    <label for="off" class="switch-off" id="btnng">う〜ん。。</label>
    <input type="radio" name="s2" id="on" value="1">
    <label for="on" class="switch-on" id="btnok">なるほど！</label>
</div>
```

server.js is bellow.

I could count the number of How many user are logging in,
but I couldn't count state of radio button on time(realtime).

I am glad if you help me.

---

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

var clients = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("ID: "+socket.id.substring(2)+"has connected");
  clients[socket.id] = {
    vote:''
  };

  io.sockets.emit('count', socket.client.conn.server.clientsCount);

  socket.on('vote', function(data){
    clients[socket.id].vote = data; // good or bad
    var result = calcVote(clients);
    io.sockets.emit('vote', result);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete clients[socket.id];
    io.sockets.emit('count', socket.client.conn.server.clientsCount);
  });
});
var calcVote = function(calcclients){
  var sums = {
    good:0,
    bad:0
  };
  calcclients.forEach(function(client){
    switch (client.vote) {
      case 'good' :
      sums.good += 1;
      break;
      case 'bad' :
      sums.bad += 1;
      break;
    }
  });
  return sums;
};

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3010, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log("Chat server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
node.js socket.io
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your `clients` variable as an array, but you are not using it as an array.  Instead, you are just assigning properties to the `clients` variable which are not array elements.  Therefore when you try to use `.forEach()` to iterate the connected users, it doesn't do what you want because `.forEach()` iterates only array elements, but you've just assigned properties to the array, not array elements.  So, your `.forEach()` doesn't iterate anything.

Change to:

```
var clients = {};
```

And, then use an iteration method that iterates properties such as `for/in` or `for/of` or get the property names into an array with `Object.keys()` and iterate those.

For example:

```
var calcVote = function(calcclients){
  var sums = {
    good:0,
    bad:0
  };
  Object.keys(calcclients).forEach(function(id){
    var client = calcclients[id];
    switch (client.vote) {
      case 'good' :
      sums.good += 1;
      break;
      case 'bad' :
      sums.bad += 1;
      break;
    }
  });
  return sums;
};
```